# Ionization and bond energy of isotope

Tags: bond, ionization-energy, isotope

Is there a database with the direct values, or the ingredients to calculate them, for ionization and bond energies of isotopes (i.e. $^{17}O_2$). If I understand it right, ionization energy can be calculated using the atom radius but I cannot find such information for isotopes and I guess it's still slightly different to the one of the abundand forms. Also, for bond energy I read it can be calculated using enthalpies but can't find such data for isotopes either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's "O_17"? If you have **di**oxygen-17 in mind, then it should be $\ce{^{17}O2}.$

Comment: Ah, good point, I meant dioxygen indeed, changed it in the question, thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? You must realize that the internal energy and kinetic of oxygen molecules varies tremendously compared to the difference between isotopic changes. The difference in binding energy  even between hydrogen and deuterium atoms is tiny. // You should be able to get a very reasonable estimate using the difference in the reduced mass.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such tables. For chemistry the values are so close as to make no difference except for very light elements such as hydrogen.

All in all you should be able to get a good idea of the difference by using the difference in reduced mass, $m_\mathrm{r}$.

$$m_\mathrm{r} = \dfrac{m_\mathrm{electron}m_\mathrm{nucleus}}{m_\mathrm{electron}+m_\mathrm{nucleus}} = m_\mathrm{electron}\cdot   \dfrac{1}{1+ \dfrac{m_\mathrm{electron}}{m_\mathrm{nucleus}}}$$

So for $\ce{^{16}O}$

$$m_\mathrm{r,\ce{^{16}O}} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{5.489\cdot10^{-4}}{15.995}} = ‭0.9999657$$

for $\ce{^{17}O}$

$$m_\mathrm{r,\ce{^{17}O}} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{5.489\cdot10^{-4}}{16.999}} = ‭0.9999677$$

% Difference between $m_\mathrm{r,\ce{^{17}O}}$ and $m_\mathrm{r,\ce{^{16}O}}$ = +0.00020%